# Why is it enough to prove the sentence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, volume

I am looking at the proof of the theorem that for any rectangle the outer measure is equal to the volume.

At the beginning of the proof there is the following sentence:

It is enough to look at the case where the rectangle R is closed and bounded.

Why does it stand?

Comment: Try to fill the gap on your own. What if the rectangle is not bounded? What if it is not closed (which, by the way does not imply that it is open)?

Comment: A closed rectangle is $$[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2, b_2] \times \dots \times [a_d, b_d]$$
An open rectangle is $$(a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2) \times \dots \times (a_d, b_d)$$ which can written as a union of closed intervals, right??

Comment: @Dirk Is this correct??

Answer (score 0):

Let $M^*$ the outer measure, $M$ the measure, defined on open sets.

1. If the rectangle is not bounded, then both measures are $\infty$.
2. Now assume that the rectangle is bounded. Consider a non-closed rectangle, that is a measurable set $R$ such as
   $$
   \prod_{i=1}^d (a_i,b_i) \subset R
   \subset \prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i]
   $$
   Then it is known that $R$ has the same volume as
   $$\prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i]
   $$
   And if $O$ is an open set such as $\prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i] \subset O$ then
   $
   R\subset O
   $ as well, and so $M^*(R) \le M^*(\prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i])$
3. Now assume that $R\subset O$, with $O$ an open set.
   Let $r>0$ be a small number. Then
   $$
   \prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i]
   \subset O \cup \prod (a_i -r,b_i+r)
   $$ and $$
   M\left( O \cup \prod (a_i -r,b_i+r) \right)
   \downarrow_{r\downarrow 0} M(O)
   $$
   so $M^*(R) = \inf_{R\subset O \text{ open}} M(O) \ge M^*(\prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i])$

Comment: 2. Could you explain me what you mean by "colume" ?? $$$$ When $R$ is bounded and non-closed, does it stand that $$\Pi_{i=1}^{d}(a_i, b_i) \subset R \subset \Pi_{i=1}^{d}[a_i, b_i]$$ because $R$ is non-closed, so it can be covered by closed rectangles and it contains open rectangles?? $$$$ Why do we have to say that "if $O$ is an open set such as $\Pi_{i=1}^{d}[a_i, b_i] \subset O$ then $R \subset O$, so $M^*(R) \leq M^*(\Pi_{i=1}^{d}[a_i, b_i])$"?? Wouldn't the inequality $M^*(R) \leq M^*(\Pi_{i=1}^{d}[a_i, b_i])$ stand if there is not such a set $O$??

Comment: this is a typo for volume

Comment: for the last part, I agree. I just wanted to say that this was a consequence of the inclusion of the set of opening covers of $R$  into the closed rectangle.

Comment: I got stuck right now.. Do we have shown now that it is sufficient to look at the case where the rectangle R is closed and bounded??

Comment: yes, because for any rectangle $R$ defined  as I told you (which is the most general way), the outer mesure and the volume of $R$ are the same as the outer mesure and the volume of $prod_{i=1}^d [a_i,b_i]$.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me? At the proof, we prove the sentence when R is closed and bounded. Do we apply this result to show that it is also true when R is not closed and bounded?? I am really confused right now...

Comment: yes, once you made the move described here, you apply the result showed for the closed rectangles. as: 1. (outer mesure)(R) = (outer mesure)(closed rectangle) 2. volume(R) = volume(closed rectangle) 3. (outer mesure)(closed rectangle) = volume(closed rectangle) you got the desired result: (outer mesure)(R) = volume(R)

Comment: Could you also explain me the point $3.$ ??

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: also, please use @mookid in order to make me see your post.

Comment: it looks like I'm gonna get squeezed.